# C# BinaryFormatter Serialize UserControl

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

Is it possible to use the BinaryFormatter Serialize/Deserialize methods to serialize and deserialize a class that contains UI objects?  I know it's likely not recommended and only data should really be serialized, but is there a reason why it would not be supported technically?

Say, for example, I had a class such as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<UC1> _ucList1 = new List<UC1>();
    private List<UC2> _ucList2 = new List<UC2>();

    public MyClass() {}
}
```

In the above theoretical class, UC1 and UC2 are of type UserControl - so a list of user controls.  Is there a reason why that could not be deserialized?  I did some testing and it appears to serialize into a byte array fine, but the deserialization routine throws an exception "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should use the standard Component Serialization.
The binary formatter will ignore for example extended properties, design only properties and will not invoke the BeginInit/EndInit of components that implement ISupportInitialize.
I don't know what it would do on Delegates (Events), probably it will fail to serialize them.

Finally if I remember well none of the classes in WinForms is decorated with the Serializable attribute

Comment: What are u referring to when you say "standard component serialization"?

Comment: It's the whole framework under System.ComponentModel, System.ComponentModel.Design, System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.  For example see this decent sample project http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813808 It can serialize the winforms controls to XML